# getting user's geolocation, the app displays the lat and lng but can't get the reverse geocode for the city name of the user's

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary

The code has the ability to show and display the user's location lat and lng but can not show the name of the city the geolocation. I would like to see the user's location instead of the geolocation.

```js
function findMyGeolocation() {

  const status = document.querySelector('#status');
  const mapLink = document.querySelector('#latlong-display');

  mapLink.href = '';
  mapLink.textContent = '';

     // Declaring lat/long as variables.
  function success(position) {
    const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;


    // INSERTING THE API LINK HERE WITH THE KEY TO FETCH DATA.
    status.textContent = '';
    mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`; /* LINK FOR THE MAP*/
    mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`; /* PROVIDING CONTENT*/
  }

     // User did not approve geolocation access.
  function error() {
    status.textContent = 'Not able location access!';
  }
     //Incase success of accessing user's location, get geolocation
  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'Updating your location .....';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }

}

document.querySelector('#getGeolocation').addEventListener('onClick', findMyGeolocation);
```

```html
<button type="button" id = "getGeolocation" onClick =" findMyGeolocation()" placeholder=" update location" >Check</button>

<div id="status"></div>
<h1 id="latlong-display"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get city name from the geocoordinates, you need to use Reverse geocoding API.

Try BigDataCloud's free client-side reverse geocoding API.

Here is one solution, implement the following function to retrieve locality name using [BigDataCloud API](https://www.bigdatacloud.com/geocoding-apis/free-reverse-geocode-to-city-api).

```
function idLocation(lat, long) {

  //Create query for the API.
  var latitude = "latitude=" + lat;
  var longitude = "&longitude=" + long;
  var query = latitude + longitude + "&localityLanguage=en";

  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var bigdatacloud_api =
    "https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?";

  bigdatacloud_api += query;

  Http.open("GET", bigdatacloud_api);
  Http.send();

  Http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(myObj);
      return myObj.locality;
    }
  };
}
```